# How to stop webcam streaming in C# program?

Tags: c#, user-interface, webcam

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       cap = new Capture();
        Application.Idle += new EventHandler(showFromCam);
        button1.Hide();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        button1.Show();
    }
```

Using above code, I get webcam streaming into my application by clicking on button1. I need to close webcam by clicking button2. Can anybody suggest any method to do it? Thanks.

Comment: What is the Capture class?  Does that have a method to stop streaming?

Comment: I suppose where the showFromCam method comes from lies another method that stops the cam.

Comment: no capture() from emgucv, I think.

Comment: this is showFromCam class ` void showFromCam(Object render, EventArgs e) {
            img = cap.QueryFrame().ToBitmap();
            pictureBox1.Image = img;
        }`

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the similar problem and I found a solution of my problem. You should call `stop()` and `dispose()` method.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // stop the camera
    cap.Stop();
    cap.Dispose(); 

    button1.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think You should use
grabber = new Capture();
grabber.QueryFrame();`Application.Idle -= FrameGrabber;`grabber.Dispose();`